# Pattern matching by regular expression for special characters in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to collect all values from an xml which contains special characters, because XmlDocunemt and XDocument throw exception reading xml contains special char in c#.

Say, I got an xml string

```
<root>\n\t<childone>\n\t\t<attributeone name=\"aa\">aa</attributeone>\n\t\t<attributetwo adds=\"ba\">ab&\"'<</attributetwo>\n\t\t<attributeone name=\"aa\">&</attributeone>\n\t</childone>\n</root>
```

I'm using following code segment to get only those values which contains special char such as "ab&"'<" and "&"

```
string pat = @"(>)([&\""\'<]+)(<)(/)";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but it does not capture any. So, what will be the best way to capture all values contain special char and store them in string array or list. My input is xml string with special char and in some cases it may not contain any new line char or tab between tags and is some xml contains 17000+ lines. And after capturing then I need to replace those special chars by comparable type (& to &). Please help me to find a good way to solve the problem.
(it only captures string contains char specified id "pat" string such as "&&&", or "<'" but cannot "aa&" or "&&jh" and only captures the first occurrence).

Comment: As many will likely point out, parsing XML with regex is generally a bad idea as it gets out of hand rather quickly, is hard to maintain and it is often hard to foresee possible bugs, especially if your input changes. There's a number of well-written XML parsers out there, it's better to pick one and go with that than to use regex for this job.

Comment: Agree with Nit that you should try to avoid regexes. You say "because XmlDocunemt and XDocument throw exception reading xml" - I would suggest fixing the application that produces the apparently invalid xml input string, e.g. by letting it properly escape the special characters. Xml is no good unless it can be read by normal xml parsers.

Comment: @Astrotrain I understand the situation you described but unfortunately I do not have much access to XML source. I just can get it from the source as input string. But I don't know where or who creates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformatted your xml fragment so that it's more readable. It can clearly be seen that the xml is not valid (which we already knew, because the XmlDocument failed to parse it).
Apparently, attributetwo's content is supposed to be `ab&\"'<`, but there isn't a single xml parser that will understand that because of the "&" (which should be a "`&amp;`") and the last "<" (which should be a "`&lt;`"):

```
<root>\n
\t<childone>\n
\t\t<attributeone name=\"aa\">aa</attributeone>\n
\t\t<attributetwo adds=\"ba\">ab&\"'<</attributetwo>\n
\t\t<attributeone name=\"aa\">&</attributeone>\n
\t</childone>\n
</root>
```

I still think you should try to get this string transformed into valid xml, so that you can parse it.
This might be a way to do it (this example requires that '{' and '}' are not used in the actual xml string, although you could use any two unused characters):

```
class Program
{
    private const string BrokenXml = 
        "<root>\n" +
        "\t<childone>\n" +
        "\t\t<attributeone name=\"aa\">aa</attributeone>\n" +
        "\t\t<attributetwo adds=\"ba\">ab&\"'<</attributetwo>\n" +
        "\t\t<attributeone name=\"aa\">&</attributeone>\n" +
        "\t<empty />\n" +
        "\t</childone>\n" +
        "</root>";

    // Matches an opening tag with 0 or more attributes, and captures everything within "<...>" as Groups[1].
    // Unescaped regex looks like: <(\w+(?:\s+\w+="[^"]*")?)>
    private static Regex OpenTagRegex = new Regex("<(\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+=\"[^\"]*\")?)>");

    // Matches a close tag and captures everything within "<...>" as Groups[1].
    private static Regex CloseTagRegex = new Regex("<(/\\w+)>");

    // Matches an empty tag and captures everything within "<...>" as Groups[1].
    private static Regex EmptyTagRegex = new Regex("<(\\w+\\s*/)>");

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Replace the angular brackets (<>) of all valid xml elements with curly brackets ({})
        string step1 = OpenTagRegex.Replace(BrokenXml, ReplaceMatch);
        string step2 = CloseTagRegex.Replace(step1, ReplaceMatch);
        string step3 = EmptyTagRegex.Replace(step2, ReplaceMatch);

        //Fix the remaining special characters with their xml entity counterparts:
        string step4 = step3.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        string step5 = step4.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        string step6 = step5.Replace(">", "&gt;");

        //Convert from curly braces xml back to regular xml
        string result = step6.Replace("{", "<").Replace("}", ">");

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Matches the MatchEvaluator signature.
    /// </summary>
    private static string ReplaceMatch(Match match)
    {
        string contentWithoutAngularBrackets = match.Groups[1].Value;
        return "{" + contentWithoutAngularBrackets + "}";
    }
}
```